# continuity, pointwise convergence, bounded imply uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, upper-lower-bounds, pointwise-convergence

Let $(f_n(x))_n$ sequence of continuous functions converging to $f:R\to R$ (continuous).
Assume $|f_n-f|$ is bounded function.
Then show $f_n-f$ is uniformly bounded.

---

*Remark:*
It seems the uniformity should be done with respect to $n$.

The example I have in mind is $f_n(x)$ is a triangle of height $n$ over $[0,1/n]$ and $f_n(x)$ is zero elsewhere.
Then $f_n(x)\to 0$, $f_n$ continuous and not uniformly bounded but wait ... then I don't understand the question.

What is annoying me is the implication line 3 of the following image :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, $f_n-f$ is a bounded sequence ? For me $f_n-f$ is a function. Or is the sequence $(f_n-f)$ bounded ? For which norm ?

Comment: oups yeah function

Comment: Then the result is not true, the example in your remark is a counterexample.

Comment: The "is bounded" at the start of the fourth line means "is uniformly bounded". Otherwise one couldn't invoke Osgood's theorem. Of course it's bad to leave out the word "uniformly" there, all the more because later in that line it is again used.

Comment: ok thanks, problem solved then